# How to debug wp-admin/widgets.php

Tags: php, wordpress

In wp-config.php =>

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-admin/widgets.php#L10

I added these line of code:

```
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/admin.php' );
echo '<div style="background-color:yellow;margin-left:200px;margin-top:200px">';
echo '<pre>';
echo '<h1>Hello world</h1>';
print_r(dirname( __FILE__ ));
echo '</pre>';
echo '</div>';
```

But this is not display anything on http://localhost.localdomain/wordpress/wp-admin/widgets.php , so how can i debug some value of wp-admin/widgets.php ?

Answers will be appreciated.
Thanks.

EDIT: It is working now.

Comment: Where did you add your code?

Comment: What do `print_r(dirname( __FILE__ ));` means

Comment: @akirk, i added that code in /var/www/wordpress/wp-admin/widgets.php after the line 10.

Comment: @PieterGoosen, I hope that is supposed to print the path where admin.php file resides.

Comment: Ok, that's not where the code should go. You need to create a new file, see the answer.

Comment: Why are you editing core files?

Comment: @PieterGoosen, I am not editing core files, rather finding a way to understand it through debugging/print_r .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new file for your widget in `wp-content/plugins/`.

Check [a tutorial like this one](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-create-wordpress-widgets/).

Comment: I am not trying to write widget, rather trying to print_r in regular php way. Why isn't it working?